# use nextprobableprime() of java to get previousprobableprime

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to use `nextProbablePrime()` method of `BigInteger` to get the prime that is lower than the given number instead of higher.

Is it possible to get it using just one `nextProbablePrime` call?

Comment: +1 interesting question (though I suspect the answer is no)

Comment: Can you suggest an efficient method to get the prime lower than a given number using all of the methods available with the BigInteger class?

Comment: You could have a look at the source for this method (http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html) and see if you can modify it yourself (it's rather complicated, though)

Comment: I think it can be done. Save the `nextProbablePrime` of the number (call it `max`). Then start with the `nextProbablePrime` from zero, while the `nextProbablePrime` is smaller than `max`, continue. Until you find the `nextProbablePrime` that is `max`, then return the one before it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun "Is it possible to get it using **just one** nextProbablePrime call?" So, that's a no :-)

Comment: @Heuster I missed the most important part of the question. Maybe it's time to sleep :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's possible using the `nextProbablePrime` method (in one call). However, I just had a need for a `previousProbablePrime` method, and I came up with the following method that uses the `isProbablePrime` method in the `BigInteger` API:

```
public static BigInteger previousProbablePrime(BigInteger val) {
    // To achieve the same degree of certainty as the nextProbablePrime 
    // method, use x = 100 --> 2^(-100) == (0.5)^100.
    int certainty = 100;
    do {
        val = val.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    } while (!val.isProbablePrime(certainty));
    return val;
}
```

I set up the following test just to compare the speed (and accuracy) to the `nextProbablePrime` method:

```
private static void testPreviousProbablePrime() {
    BigInteger min = BigInteger.ONE; // exclusive
    BigInteger max = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000); // exclusive
    BigInteger val;

    // Create a list of prime numbers in the range given by min and max 
    // using previousProbablePrime method.
    ArrayList<BigInteger> listPrev = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.start();

    val = BigIntegerUtils.previousProbablePrime(max);
    while (val.compareTo(min) > 0) {
        listPrev.add(val);
        val = BigIntegerUtils.previousProbablePrime(val);
    }
    sw.stop();
    System.out.println("listPrev = " + listPrev.toString());
    System.out.println("number of items in list = " + listPrev.size());
    System.out.println("previousProbablePrime time = " + sw.getHrMinSecMsElapsed());

    System.out.println();

    // Create a list of prime numbers in the range given by min and max 
    // using nextProbablePrime method.
    ArrayList<BigInteger> listNext = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    sw.reset();
    sw.start();

    val = min.nextProbablePrime();
    while (val.compareTo(max) < 0) {
        listNext.add(val);
        val = val.nextProbablePrime();
    }
    sw.stop();
    System.out.println("listNext = " + listNext.toString());
    System.out.println("number of items in list = " + listNext.size());
    System.out.println("nextProbablePrime time = " + sw.getHrMinSecMsElapsed());

    System.out.println();

    // Compare the two lists.
    boolean identical = true;
    int lastIndex = listPrev.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
        int j = lastIndex - i;
        if (listPrev.get(j).compareTo(listNext.get(i)) != 0) {
            identical = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Lists are identical?  " + identical);
}
```

The `Stopwatch` class is just a basic custom class to track the execution time, so modify those parts to suit the class you might have for this.

I tested for the ranges from 1 to 10000, 100000, and 1000000. The `previousProbablePrime` method took longer to execute in all three tests. However, it appeared that the difference in execution time increased only modestly with each 10x increase in range size. For 10000, `previousProbablePrime` executed in just under a second, while `nextProbablePrime` came in at around 200 ms, for a difference of about 700 or 800 ms. For 1000000, the difference was only about 2 seconds, even though the execution times were 9 and 7 seconds, respectively. Conclusion, the difference in execution time increases slower than the range size.

In all tests, the two lists contained the identical set of prime numbers.

This level of efficiency was sufficient for my needs...might work for you too.

**EDIT**
Modified method implementation to be more efficient and potentially faster, though I have not tested.

```
public static BigInteger previousProbablePrime(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.compareTo(BigInteger.TWO) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value must be greater than 1.");
    }

    // Handle single unique case where even prime is returned.
    if (val.equals(new BigInteger("3"))) {
        return BigInteger.TWO;
    }

    // To achieve the same degree of certainty as the nextProbablePrime 
    // method, use x = 100 --> 2^(-100) == (0.5)^100.
    int certainty = 100;

    boolean isEven = val.mod(BigInteger.TWO).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);

    val = isEven ? val.subtract(BigInteger.ONE) : val.subtract(BigInteger.TWO);

    while (!val.isProbablePrime(certainty)) {
        // At this point, only check odd numbers.
        val = val.subtract(BigInteger.TWO);
    }

    return val;
}
```